# useState values where useContext.Provider is defined

Tags: reactjs, use-state, use-context

I am doing an app where I have some components and I've defined useStates from them, obtaining the values I  need from all of them

I've also created a Context with useContext and I wrapped my main component like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppContext } from './components/appContext/AppContext'

import { MainApp } from './MainApp'

export const App = () => {


    const testValues = {
        myDomine: 'domine name',
        mySpace: 'space name',
        color: 'red',
        persons: '5 ',
        privacidad: true

    }


    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={testValues}>
            <MainApp/>

        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

with the above testValues object I can obtain what I need in other component like this:

```
const { myDomine, mySpace} = useContext(AppContext)
```

previously importing useContext and the AppContext I've created beforehand

you see all works fine BUT

1. How can I pass my components stateValues that I've obtained individually to this testValues object?
2. Is what I am trying to achieve completly wrong?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that.

**for example**:

on provider

```
    import {useState} from 'react';
```

```
    const [testValues, setTestValues] = useState({
        myDomine: 'domine name',
        mySpace: 'space name',
        color: 'red',
        persons: '5 ',
        privacidad: true
    })
```

```
    <AppContext.Provider value={[testValues, setTestValues]}>
       <MainApp/>
    </AppContext.Provider>
```

on child component

```
    const [testValues, setTestValues] = useAuthContext();
```

**Finally**: You can use both of setTestvalues(update state) and testValues(state).

Comment: thanks for your replay, I think I  did not explain myself correctly..i am going to again: I have 5 individual components everyone of them with a finall value from a useState Hook. what I want to achieve is to pass those values to my testValues object...for instance, wouldn' t be 'domine name' instead would be componentOneValue...and so on with the others values